# Find IP address using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to get my IP using the following code:

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?", function(data){ip=data.ip});
```

But it doesn't seems to work for me. Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That website doesn't seem to be working at the moment

Comment: yes. i tried using it but it shows 503 error. Is there any other method for the same?

Comment: @user1929236 Did my answer helped you or you need more help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14251584/468718

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this site to acquire your IP with JSON.

http://jsonip.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a ajax request to your backend web server and respond to ajax request with the requesting client's ip back from the server. The code will change depending on the language of your web application.

> JavaScript itself has no way of reading the IP address of the local computer and so for JavaScript to obtain that information we need to use a different language to obtain the information.

Several snippets for server-side code options

**In JSP**

```
ip = '<%=request.getRemoteAddr()%>';
```

**In PHP**

```
ip = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>";
```

**In ASP**

```
ip = '<%= Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")%>';
```

**In ASP.NET**

```
ip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress>';
```

**In Cold Fusion**

```
ip = '<cfoutput>#cgi.remote_addr#</cfoutput>';
```

Reference: [Obtaining Your Visitor's IP Address](http://javascript.about.com/library/blip.htm)

Comment: This is correct: it is **impossible** for JavaScript alone to get the user's IP.

Answer (score 1):

Get your IP with jQuery

you can get your public IP address with one line of JS? There is a free service that offers this for you and a get request is all that you need to do:

```
   $.get('http://jsonip.com/', function(r){ console.log(r.ip); });
```

For the above snippet to work, your browser will have to support CORS (cross-origin request sharing). Otherwise
a security exception would be thrown. In older browsers, you can use this version, which uses a JSON-P request:

```
   $.getJSON('http://jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(r){ console.log(r.ip); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getip(json){
  alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
}
```

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

Comment: This site is not working now. And i need a alternative that is without any server side script and using jQuery only.